# 'Share link' from Navigator doesn't work on Messenger

Tags: javascript, navigator

This function works everywhere (WhatsApp, AirDrop, Messages) but doesn't work on Facebook Messenger.

If I enter a text e.g. "foo" while sending the link from iOS(iOS 14) from the website to the Messenger contact, only "foo" is sent to them, but not the link, although I clearly do the sharing via Navigator.share.

Are there any present bugs?

```
 inviteFromLink() {
      if (navigator.share) {
        navigator
          .share({
            title: "Title",
            text: "Join My Team!",
            url: "https://jointeam.com/"
          })
          .then(() => console.log("Successful share"))
          .catch(error => {
            // Chrome returns an error on cancelling
            // No need to display a warning on cancel...
            // this.displayWarning();
            console.log("Error sharing", error);
          });
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inviteFromLink() { 
...}
```

I think there is an error in the method definition.
try this way

```
function inviteFromLink () { ... }
```

or

```
inviteFromLink = () => { ... }
```